# Display Users with Pics and Roles in vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have an requirement where i need to display all the users with their pics and roles as inline HTMl div in vf page.
Can anybody help me out with the aproach.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a small Apex method that returns a list of users. And then implement a small pageblock table on the Visualforce page to display that list.

Apex:

```
public List<User> getUsers(){
    // Here getting ALL users of the org
    // You may have to insert some WHERE clause to limit the list results
    return [Select FirstName, LastName, SmallPhotoUrl From User];
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Users}" var="user">
        <apex:column headerValue="Name">
            {!user.FirstName} {!user.LastName}
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Photo">
            <img src="{!user.SmallPhotoUrl}" />
        </apex:column>        
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The result:

[image]

[Here you can find a complete list with all user object fields](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm)

Comment: Thanks Bro for the help..Now i want to integrate this page with google hangout. I will have a button called launch which will open google hangout. Can u plzz help...

Comment: @Sid This is another question. You will find some ideas on this forum for sure.